# How do I create a camera in java to change perspective?

Tags: java

I have a java applet that draws top left x,y(0,0) to bottom right x,y(500,500).  How would I go about having that same applet draw what is located in top left x,y(500,0) to bottom right x,y(1000,500)?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. Do you want to draw at `(500,0)` and have it appear at `(0,0)`? Could you not just offset in that case `(x - 500, y)`, `500 < x < 1000`?

Comment: Yes that is basically what I want to do, I have a large map made of many points and I want to only draw a fraction of it at at time.  Right now I am shifting the entire map around and I basically want to just move the "camera" instead of the map.

Comment: What do you want to draw? *What* is located *where*, in an image?

Comment: Its a 2d array of ints generated to represent a map. For example it may be (10000,10000) but I only want to draw (500,500) of it at a time.  But I would need to smoothly move around it with a camera or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have alot of methods available in the [Graphics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) class called drawImage.

I believe [this is the one you are after](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.Color,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29) which is able to draw a particular part of an image at a particular place on a canvas.

Edit: Based on your comment I would suggest that you draw your *map* to an Image and then use the drawImage method to draw the image from a specified offset. Every time your offset is changed, draw the image from that location instead.

Comment: that sounds pretty legit I will give it a try Thanks!